# The difference of dynamic memory, stack memory, and static memory and in c++?

Tags: c++, memory

I want to know the difference between dynamic memory, stack memory and static memory in C++.
Here is some code as an example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char *GetMemory(void)
{
    char p[]="hello world";
    char *q="hello world"; 
    return q;
}
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why is  `p` in the stack memory, but the `q` in dynamic memory?

Comment: You allocate dynamic memory using the `new` keyword in C++. `q` is not dynamically allocated. Both variables are on the stack.

Comment: Look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1021269/1374267) to see the differences between heap and stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` and `q` are both variables.  `p` is of type "array of 12 `char`" and `q` is of type "pointer to `char`".  Both `p` and `q` have automatic storage duration.  That is, they are allocated on the stack.

`q` is a pointer and it is initialized to point to the initial character of the string `"hello world"`.  This string is a string literal, and all string literals have static storage duration.

`p` is an array, so when you initialize `p` with a string literal, it causes `p` to declare an array of characters, and when it is initialized, the contents of the string literal are copied into the array.  So, when `GetMemory()` is called, space is allocated on the stack for the array `p`, and the contents of the string literal `"hello world"` are copied into that array.

No dynamic allocation is performed by your code.

---

Note that because `q` is a pointer to an array of characters that have static storage duration, it is safe to return `q` from the function:  the array to which it points will exist for the entire duration of the program.  It would not be safe to return `p`, however, because `p` ceases to exist when the function returns.

Note also that the type of `"hello world"` is `char const[12]`.  There is an unsafe implicit conversion in C++ that allows a string literal to be converted to a `char*` pointing to the initial character of the string literal.  This is unsafe because it silently drops the const-qualification.  You should always use `const char*` when handling string literals, because the characters are not modifiable.  (In the latest revision of the C++ language, C++11, this unsafe conversion has been removed.)

Answer (score 1):

> why is the the "p" in the stack memory but the "q" in the dynamic memory?

That's not true; both `p` and `q` are allocated with automatic storage duration (implemented as a stack structure).  The differences between them are:

1. `p` is an array and points to modifiable memory (stack allocated).
2. `q` is a pointer and points to readonly memory that has been allocated statically.  You really should have declared it as:

   const char *p = "whatever";

There is no dynamic allocation here.  You didn't call `new`, `malloc`, or some routine which uses those behind the scenes to allocate memory.  As a result, it is incorrect to return `p` from this function as it will be invalid once the function returns.

Comment: A bit of clarification: The point of declaring `const char *p` is to generate compiler warning when we try to modify the data that `p` points to. Without this, one will only notice the error of modifying readonly memory when the program runs and get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

For your examples, since you are using a string literal, this is likely written into the DATA segment of the executable. There is no dynamic memory allocated. A better example is something like this:

```
void foo()
{
    //This is a stack variable. Space is allocated 
    //on the stack to store it. Its lifetime is
    //the routine that calls it.

    some_class stack_variable; 

    //This is a heap-allocated variable. It will
    //remain in memory indefinitely unless deleted.
    //If a pointer to this isn't returned, and it
    //isn't deleted by the end of the routine, this
    //will become a "memory leak".

    another_class *heap_variable = new another_class();

    //This is a (method) static variable. It retains its
    //value between method calls

    static int method_static = 1;
    ++method_static;

}
```

At the closing brace, stack_variable is cleaned up (that is, the stack space it occupied is reclaimed). heap_variable hasn't been deleted, and thus is a memory leak. If we call this method a few times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { foo(); }
```

Then method_static will have a value of 5.